# Partially Circular Join

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry, I'm new to SQL. Terminology help for improving my question title/further googling welcome. I'm sure my question has been asked but I couldn't figure out what to search.

**The problem:**

- I'm selecting a bunch of data (several columns) from Table A,
  including a principal value, Claim_Nbr.
- I'm inner joining Table B on A.Claim_Nbr = B.Claim_Nbr.
- Table B has a value, P_Claim_Nbr, that is also a Claim_Nbr, and I'd like to get all the Table A columns (Column_2, Column_3, etc.) for the B.P_Claim_Nbr s as part of my resultset.

**Notes:**

- Only some Claim_Nbr s have P_Claim_Nbr s.
- No P_Claim_Nbr s have their own P_Claim_Nbr s.
- All P_Claim_Nbr s have their own Column_2 s and Column_3 s.
- I do not have permission to create temp_tables

**What I Have So Far That Isn't Broken (Gets 70% there):**

```
select distinct A.Claim_Nbr, A.Column_2, A.Column_3, B.P_Claim_Nbr
from Table_A A
join Table_B B
on A.Claim_Nbr = B.Claim_Nbr
```

**The results I have now:**

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Claim_Nbr | Column_2 | Column_3 | P_Claim_Nbr |
|     1A    |   data1  |   data2  |      1B     |
|     2A    |   data3  |   data4  |     null    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

**What I am trying to obtain:**

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Claim_Nbr | Column_2 | Column_3 | P_Claim_Nbr |
|     1A    |   data1  |   data2  |      1B     |
|     2A    |   data3  |   data4  |     null    |
|     1B    |   data5  |   data6  |     null    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I will keep trying different joins to make this work, but help welcome.

Comment: What join types have you tried?

Comment: Two that I have tried:
1. In the query right below what I have now, `join Table_A c on B.P_Claim_Nbr = C.Claim_Nbr` and then switching all the A.s in the select to C.s
2. Changing `join Table_B B` to `left join Table_B B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question--which I might not--I think you can get there with a UNION.

```
--you orginal rs
SELECT A.Claim_Nbr, A.Column_2, A.Column_3, B.P_Claim_Nbr
  FROM Table_A A
  JOIN Table_B B ON A.Claim_Nbr = B.Claim_Nbr

UNION --get only distinct values from the combined result sets

--plus all the records form the next level deep.
SELECT A2.Claim_Nbr, A2.Column_2, A2.Column_3, NULL
  FROM Table_A A
  JOIN Table_B B on A.Claim_Nbr = B.Claim_Nbr 
  JOIN TABLE_A A2 ON B.P_Claim_Nbr = A2.Claim_Nbr
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me solve the problem where if I did `join Table A c` and then replaced all the A.s with C.s, none of the A results (Claims 1A and 2A) would show up, only the C.s (1B). Thank you!

Comment: Any suggestions on what to rename the question?

Comment: It's more of a circular join than a recursive join. I might title it 'Partially Circular Join' and not worry about it beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tableA table(Claim_Nbr varchar(2))

insert into @tableA
select '1A' union all
select '2A'

declare @tableB table(Claim_Nbr varchar(2), Column_2 varchar(max), Column_3 varchar(max), P_Claim_Nbr varchar(2))

insert into @tableB(Claim_Nbr, Column_2,Column_3, P_Claim_Nbr)
select '1A', 'data1', 'data2', '1B' union all
select '2A', 'data3', 'data4', null union all
select '1B', 'data5', 'data6', null


;with cte as
(
    select b.*
    from @tableA a 
        join @tableB b on a.Claim_Nbr = b.Claim_Nbr
    union all
    select b.*
    from cte c
        join @tableB b on b.Claim_Nbr = c.P_Claim_Nbr   
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. There are a few problems with this. 1. I do not have permissions to create temp tables. (I added a note above, thanks). 2. This would require me to brute force collect all of the data myself and set up the tables myself. This does technically achieve what I was asking, but the above is a simplified version of what I am actually doing and I am trying to preserve a few more intra-data relationships that this method would rule out. Thank you for trying.

Comment: The temp tables (okay they are table variables) are likely intended only to set up some sample data to show the solution working.

Comment: There are no needed in creating temp tables, just use code started from ;with cte as and replace tableA to Table_A and tableB to Table_B

Comment: @Oleg Ah, well this is what I see when I run the above query (I'm putting "/" between lines of the error for readability): ORA-06550: line 1, column 9: /
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following: / 

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier> / 
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete / 
   exists prior

Comment: That's because you've been given TSQL variable declarations even though you specified Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not noticed that question about oracle, in oracle recursive queries have another syntax, but you can change this query as described in this article https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53139879276132